# SwiftUI - How to make ScrollView not bounce when content is smaller than bounds

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiscrollview

I'm trying to make my `ScrollView`:

- **Not bounce** when the content is smaller than the screen
- **Bounce** when the content overflows the screen

Here's my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UIScrollView.appearance().alwaysBounceVertical = false
    }
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(height: 300) /// is smaller than the screen
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

I tried setting [`UIScrollView.appearance().alwaysBounceVertical = false`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619383-alwaysbouncevertical), but the scroll view still bounces:

[image: Swiping vertically on ScrollView, but still bounces]

If I do `UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = false`, it stops bouncing. However, if I make the rectangle taller than the screen, it also stops bouncing (which I don't want).

| Doesn't bounce (yay!) | ... but doesn't bounce when the content overflows the screen |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Swiping vertically on ScrollView with short rectangle doesn't bounce] | [image: Swiping vertically on ScrollView with tall rectangle also doesn't bounce] |

How can I disable bouncing, but only when the content is smaller than scroll view's bounds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From **iOS 16.4** onwards, there is a new modifier for called `.scrollBounceBehavior` that can be used to prevent ScrollView from bouncing when the content is smalled than the screen.

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.blue)
                .frame(height: 300)
                .padding()
        }
        .scrollBounceBehavior(.basedOnSize)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Awesome, where did you find this modifier?

Comment: @aheze https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/scrollbouncebehavior(_:axes:)?changes=latest_minor

Comment: As an additional note, if you are building for Mac OS, the requirement is 13.3 or later

Answer (score 6):

For iOS 16.4+, see @JuvinR's answer

---

Well, when using [`SwiftUI-Introspect`](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect), setting `alwaysBounceVertical` to `false` actually works. I'm not exactly sure why setting the appearance as you did doesn't work though...

Anyway, here is some working example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var count = 5
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Count", selection: $count) {
                Text("5").tag(5)
                Text("100").tag(100)
            }
            .pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(1 ... count, id: \.self) { i in
                        Text("Item: \(i)")
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            .introspectScrollView { scrollView in
                scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result (unfortunately you can't see my mouse trying to drag the shorter list):

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, works great! Preferable I'd try to avoid any libraries, but unless someone finds a better way I'll leave your answer checked.

Comment: "not exactly sure why setting the appearance as you did doesn't work" I have a suspicion that SwiftUI overrides the default somehow... back in UIKit I think `alwaysBounceVertical` was `false` by default, so it didn't bounce unless you set that to `true`.

Comment: @aheze Possibly. And it must be set before it is rendered, because even with a timer setting the appearance multiple times per second doesn't work either (showing it's not a timing issue of when you set the appearance in your init).

Comment: i hope we can have a solution without relying on third party libraries.

Comment: @John It’s highly unlikely Apple would make any Introspection-like extension to SwiftUI, so either they make a modifier for this or you rebuild in UIKit. I’d suggest filing feedback for missing modifiers like this, but at the same time, radars are like an empty void

Answer (score 0):

Made a small extension based on George's answer using `SwiftUI-Introspect`:

```
extension View {
    func disableBouncingWhenNotScrollable() -> some View {
        introspectScrollView { scrollView in
            scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
            scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ScrollView {
    // content
}
.disableBouncingWhenNotScrollable()
```