# Make a text element always "two lines"

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-text

I have a vertical stack like this

```
VStack
  Text(lineA)
    .lineLimit(2)

  Text(lineB)

  Text(lineC)
}
```

Don't ask me why. My bosses decided that they want the first `Text` always with two lines, even if the lineA variable has no characters to make the Text grow to two lines.

Is there a way to make the first Text to render if it is two lines and to still show the reticences if there is more than 2 lines?

I can see using a frame to do that, a kind of suicide, fixing the height to a value in points that may vary from device to device.

Is there a less lethal solution?

Comment: In which place should you break `lineA`?

Comment: First text element should use all the horizontal size available and break at words

Comment: You may be able to use [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect)... it worked for me [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67248813/14351818)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following `@Asperi` brilliant idea, I tested another option that worked better for me:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("asdfasfdasfasfasfafddafas\n")
            .lineLimit(2)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

        Text("lineB")
        Text("lineC")
    }
}
```

This will make it 2 lines even if the text is only enough for one and if the text exceeds two lines, the reticences will be added.

Answer (score 4):

Here is possible solution (tested with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4)

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("X\nX").foregroundColor(.clear)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .overlay(
                Text("sdfasdfasdfasd asd f asdf asd f asdf asd fas df ")
//              Text("sdfasdfasdfasd asd f asdf asd f asdf asd fas df asdf asd fa sdf asdfasdfasd asdf as df asdfasdf asdf")
            , alignment: .top)

        Text("lineB")
        Text("lineC")
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is actually very clever

Comment: SIMPLY BRILLIANT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: If replace "X\nX" with " \n ", it may not need `.foregroundColor(.clear)`