# UILabel Minimum Number Of Lines

Tags: swift

If you take a close look an an iMessage conversation cell, you’ll notice that the preview text is always two lines long. This can’t be a hard coded row height because the rows adjust to dynamic type. How can you always force a label to take up a certain number of lines even if there isn’t enough text to do so?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620539-numberoflines ?

Comment: No. That will give you the maximum lines allowed. I’m looking for a minimum number allowed. I only want to show two lines. Never anymore, never any less. If the content is greater than the given two lines it will truncate (that’s what the code you sent does), if it’s less than the given space the second lines should be blank, but still be there.

Comment: Just manipulate your string to add a new empty line or with spaces if needed

Comment: SwiftUI or UIKit? For SwiftUI there was a [similar question recently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67269159/14351818)

Comment: @aheze This is for UIKit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the label's `numberOfLines` to `2` and end the label's `text` with a linefeed `\n`. Set the wrapping to word wrap to prevent the ellipses from appearing.

This guarantees that the label text consists of *at least* 2 lines worth of material. Thus it can never be *less* than 2 lines, and since the maximum number of lines is 2, it can never be *more* than 2 lines. Thus it will always be (wait for it) 2 lines.

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer; it works perfectly! I was for sure over thinking this problem.

Comment: And yet when I suggested this in a comment you rejected the idea.

Comment: The comment was just a little unclear. Providing this example was very helpful. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

One way I think this could be possible is having a `UIView` as a parent of the `UILabel`.

1. Fix the height of the `UIView` based on device size class. Let's say for example 50 points for Width = Compact and Height = Regular.
2. Embed `UILabel` in `UIView`
3. Set number of Lines = 0 for `UILabel`
4. Now match `UILabel` leading , trailing ,top edge with the superview and leave the height as it is , also don't set the bottom constraints.
5. Select the superview i.e the `UIView` and `UILabel` together and select Equal Heights.

Open the constraint window and change label height less than or equal to  SuperView height.

Short Message

[image]

Long Message

[image]

Height Constraint of the UILabel with respect to SuperView.

[image]