# SwiftUI - How to Preallocating space for multiple lines of text

Tags: swiftui

In my view I have some text that changes. So ...

```swift
Text("Text that changes and may wrap")
```

Because there are multiple of these text on screen as well as other SwiftUI components I want the text components to occupy the space required for two lines of text regards of how much text they contain. This is so when the text changes the UI doesn't jink around due to the text resizing.

So I'd like these two to occupy the same space:

```
+-------------------------------+
| A short piece of text         |
|                               |
+-------------------------------+
```

```
+-------------------------------+
| A longer piece of text that   |
| wraps around.                 |
+-------------------------------+
```

However I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this as there doesn't appear to be any property of a `Text` component that specifies how many lines to display.

anyone know how to specify the height of a text component based on the lines? Some sort of fixed size based on the font and line spacing perhaps?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/67270019/12299030?

Comment: Thanks for the link it worked. However I ended up doing a similar thing with a `ZStack` instead of an overlay which I felt was a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone whose interested, here's what I ended up doing:

```swift
ZStack {

    // This creates the vertical space of two lines so the
    // actual text doesn't change size when it wraps to two lines.
    Text("\n")
        .foregroundColor(.clear)

    Text(variableText)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
        .lineLimit(2)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything gets easier

```
Text(variableText)
        .lineLimit(2, reservesSpace: true)
```

Comment: As long as you can target iOS 16.

Comment: @ChadParker you are right. And much easier with iOS 17 target )

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70616567/11841176

create extension for above commend

```
 struct ReservesSpaceViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    let lineLimit: Int
    let reservesSpace: Bool
    let font: SwiftUI.Font?
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if reservesSpace {
            ZStack(alignment: .top){
                Text("\n")
                    .frame(width: 10)
                    .foregroundColor(.clear)
                    .font(font)
                
                content
                    .lineLimit(lineLimit)
            }
        } else {
            content
                .lineLimit(lineLimit)
        }
    }
}

extension Text {
    func lineLimit(_ limit: Int,
                   reservesSpace: Bool,
                   font: SwiftUI.Font) -> some View {
        return self
            .modifier(ReservesSpaceViewModifier(lineLimit: limit, 
                                                reservesSpace: reservesSpace,
                                                font: font))
    }
}
```

How to use

```
 Text("Hello world")
      .lineLimit(2, reservesSpace: true, font: <Font>)
```